# Migrating data from AWS RDS to another RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, migration, cloud

I have a requirement to migrate data from RDS (SQL Server) to another rds (SQL Server) instance through VPN (or by bypassing VPN). What could be the ideal way to achieve this?

Comment: Not necessarily ideal, but here's what the documentation suggests: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try AWS DMS(Data migration service) it is a very neat and fast way to migrate RDS
https://aws.amazon.com/dms/